# different aggregation on same columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to do the aggregation on different column and **different aggregation on same columns** also i.e. in below example I am calculating sum on stake_amount and count on log win. However, I need to calculate mean on stake_amount and rename as average in this code.following one is working as long as I am doing **one aggregation** on stake_amount but as soon as I try to add another aggregation as **mean** it shows only mean, **not sum** please help... following is working as one aggregation.

```
table_name.groupby(['WIN_RETURN_SIZE']).
agg({'LOG_WIN':'count','STAKE_AMOUNT':'sum'})
.rename(columns={'LOG_WIN':'FREQUENCY','STAKE_AMOUNT':'QUANTITY'})
.reset_index()
```

when I need to do this (get sum and mean on same column with all other aggregation here)

```
FF_MEGAWAYS.groupby(['WIN_RETURN_SIZE']).
agg({'LOG_WIN':'count','STAKE_AMOUNT':'sum','STAKE_AMOUNT':'mean'}).
rename(columns={'LOG_WIN':'FREQUENCY','STAKE_AMOUNT':'QUANTITY'})
.reset_index()
```

Any help will be appricated

Answer (score 0):

Use named aggregation for new columns names with tuple by column with specify aggregate function:

```
(FF_MEGAWAYS.groupby(['WIN_RETURN_SIZE'], as_index=False)
            .agg(FREQUENCY=('LOG_WIN','count'),
                 QUANTITY=('STAKE_AMOUNT','sum'),
                 AVG=('STAKE_AMOUNT','mean')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list of aggregation functions after column name.

```
FF_MEGAWAYS.groupby(['WIN_RETURN_SIZE']).
agg({'LOG_WIN':'count','STAKE_AMOUNT':['sum','mean']}).
rename(columns={'LOG_WIN':'FREQUENCY','STAKE_AMOUNT':'QUANTITY'})
.reset_index()
```

Comment: stake amount have to aggregation, how would you rename the aggregated columns where it is mean considering sum is "Quantity"